# How to monitor remote git changes and auto pull?

Tags: node.js, git, github

I have a Windows server running a node.js program.
Currently, I deploy code to it manually by pushing to github, and then log into the server, and manually run:

```
git pull
npm i
nodemon app.js
```

How can I make the server monitor remote changes on a certain git branch, auto pull, (and consequently npm install and re-run the node.js app) whenever there's a new commit on git?

Comment: You are literally asking how to build a CI/CD system.

Comment: I was trying to avoid building a CI/CD system. I understand there're no shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI/CD will resolve your problem

> CI/CD automates your builds, testing, and deployment so you can ship code changes faster and more reliably.

If you use github:
[CI/CD on Github](https://resources.github.com/ci-cd/)

If you use gitlab ():
[CI/CD on Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `git` has such a feature. But you could run a [cronjob](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-with-windows) that executes your code every day at a specific time.

Comment: Thanks. There must be a tool to do this. I don't want to implement CD/CI as it would be too much for my project, but I'm sure there is a better way to monitor remote git changes and pull automatically

Comment: @MickMorely *I don't want to implement CD/CI as it would be too much for my project*. It's not too much. At its core, it's "automating the tasks that you're performing manually right now", which is what you're asking for help with.